# How do I change the background color of the label text of a C# ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a property form where the background color of label text should be changed when the data in the control has been modified.
For TextBox and CheckBox controls I have managed to achieve this, but for ComboBox I cannot find a way to modify the background color of the label text.

The BackColor property only modifies the background color of the items inside the ComboBox and I don't want to change the color inside the box.

Comment: What is the *label text* of a `ComboBox`? Can you be more clear on what you want to change. Try to refer to the actual naming convention when naming components and/or their parts. You'll get better feedback. *don't want to change the color inside the box.*. Same.

Comment: Ok, I had misunderstood things regarding the combo box and the question is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using the draw item event and brushes...
Example below:

       private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
                    Brush brush = null;
                    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox) sender;
                    e.DrawBackground();

                    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, e.Bounds);  //blue background
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("your string here", combo.Font, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y); //red font

        }
```

Comment: What is `ComboBox combo;`? That Red brush is mis-treated. The Blue brush is happier. (It's not political stuff, right? :). The OP will be missing some information on how to get the `DrawItem` method working. I'ld also fill the rectangle before drawing the text. `SmoothingMode` is useless here. Maybe you meant `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;`